# PHP echo - combining phrase and apostrophe

Tags: php, echo

I am quite new with PHP so please do not expect me to know advanced techniques...

I currently have

```
$cat = "A Phrase Here"
```

Where it results to

```
A Phrase Here
```

And the following code:

```
$cat = "'$cat'";
echo $cat;
```

Because I want it the end result to be:

```
'A Phrase Here'
```

However, what's coming out is:

```
' A Phrase Here '
```

How may I get rid of that extra space before the 'A' and after the 'Here' ?

Thank you.

**edit**

It seems that the original `$cat` had the problematic whitespaces and required a `trim` to fix. I am sorry to everyone for the misunderstanding.

Comment: $cat = "'A Phrase Here'" and then echo $cat?

Comment: tip: it would be better to give the first variable another name so you can keep the apart.

Comment: Try escaping the apostrophe's (`$cat = "\'$cat\'";`).

Comment: What's the result of `var_dump($cat)` before and after the second assignment?

Comment: Also, is there any reason it cannot all be done in your first line? `$cat = "\'A Phrase Here\'"`?

Comment: You don't have to escape single quote marks within double quotation strings.

Comment: Ah, it seems that the spaces are part of the original $cat. I apologize to everyone for the misrepresentation of the original information. May I please ask how I may remove this extra spacing so that I may add the apostrophes?

Comment: `$cat = "'". trim($cat) . "'";` as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

`$cat = "'$cat'"` works completely fine.

If you see extra spaces, it means that the original string contains them. You can remove them with [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Answer (score 0):

`echo` is not the only option. Use `printf()`:

```
$cat = "A Phrase Here"
printf("'%s'", trim($cat) );
```

to avoid problems with variable substitution in `'` delimited strings.

EDIT: `trim()` added: http://php.net/trim

Comment: Just tested it, but the spacing is still showing up.

Comment: Do a trim() on the string $cat.

Comment: You copied my code above to clear PHP file, executed it and you see spaces? This is **not possible**. If you see spaces then you added it to your `$cat` variable content, somewhere, or perhaps you test it in console with some crappy font that looks like having spaces around `'`. There's no other way - spaces do not come out of nowhere.

Comment: "problems with variable substitution in ' delimited strings" - he doesn't use `'` delimited strings...

Comment: @Cthulhu doing `trim()` is silly. You shall fix the origin of the problem not implement a workaround.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: irrelevant. my code doesn't either. Both your and mine code end with desired result - the problem is elsewhere. font?

Comment: Please read user's comment on the question. It is `$cat` that had the space, and he now wants the spaces removed. So it should suffice in this case.

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding. I do appreciate everyone's responses and have read through all of them.

Comment: @Cthulhu I answered the question which do not state that. I see the comment now. OP: update your question and pay more attention to problem description next time, please.

Comment: I've updated the original post. I am sorry for the misrepresentation. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com: ?? the sentence I quoted from you is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need for the second assign, so:

```
$cat = "A Phrase Here";
echo $cat; // this is enough

$cat = "A Phrase here";
$cat = $cat . ", and this should be an extra string";
echo $cat;

$cat = "     this string with many white spaces    ";
echo trim($cat); // will trim the white spaces before and after the string;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have extra spaces already it's not the assignment and it's not the `echo` line. To ensure no extra spaces will be passed you can use `trim`:

```
$cat = "'".trim($cat)."'";
```

but it's better to review your code and find where the spaces are being added. (or just `var_dump` everything)